# Wolfram Workbench doesn't launch Mathematica

Tags: workbench, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse, JDK 14, and Wolfram Workbench on my computer. I have made sure to specify the location of my Mathematica install. However, when I try to open a Mathematica notebook from Eclipse, I am prompted to enter my Mathematica activation key.

However, I don't think this is necessary since my installation of Mathematica is valid. When I exit that window I am greeted with this:

[image]

Also note that I specified the Mathematica 12.0 folder in Preferences, not just the Mathematica executable file.

Comment: did you sort this out?  I am seeing similar behavior.

Comment: For me, the cause was an old version's path in the preferences (9.0 instead of 12.2). Check if the system explorer opens your Mathematica.exe when you input the file path.